# How to make the Django light weight server loads quickly

Tags: django, python-2.7

When I run my Django Project in my local, Using Python manage.py runserver
It takes too long to load, or reload after a change is made in the local *.py files.How Do i make it faster, So I can quickly reload my project when ever a file is changed.

Comment: the deprecation errors are not the part that makes it slow, it would still have to do the same amount of work if you hid the errors but you would see nothing in the console while it was happening

Comment: ok. thank you, I will edit the question a bit. I want to make the loading faster, Its taking more than 10 seconds now

Answer (score 2):

It could be taking a while due to time of database connections opening. Are you running your database locally?

You can also enable things like auto-reload based on code changes by installing the [`django-extensions`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) and using `./manage.py runserver_plus`.

Also look at using the [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to profile SQL queries and look at what is coming through to your app.